# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 - admin password reset using chpasswd.bat due to a UserStoreException

Tags: ant, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to reset `admin` user password by using `chpasswd.bat` as forgot my old password in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 by follows [this link](https://medium.com/@kosalasananthana/changing-password-in-wso2-carbon-products-5dd5c808587e)

OS: windows 10

**prerequisite:**

- Apache Ant 1.10.7 has been installed in my machine.

[image: apache ant]

- environment variable set done.

[image: env variable]

[image: path for ant home]

- Since i am using default H2 Database, Copied related H2 JDBC driver into `<PRODUCT_HOME>/lib/`

[image: h2 jar]

- goto product path `<PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/`  and execute below command

chpasswd.bat --db-driver "org.h2.Driver" --db-url "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000" --db-username "wso2carbon" --db-password "wso2carbon" --username "admin" --new-password "newadmin"

after executing above command getting below log

```
C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\bin>chpasswd.bat --db-url "jdbc:h2:$CARBON_HOME\repsitory\database\WSO2CARBON_DB"
Buildfile: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\bin\build.xml

setup:
     [copy] Copying 40 files to C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\tmp\setup
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\components\plugins\org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.stub_5.12.387.jar into C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\tmp\setup
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\components\plugins\org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui_5.12.387.jar into C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\tmp\setup
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\components\plugins\org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt_5.12.387.jar into C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\tmp\setup
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\tmp\setup
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\components\plugins\h2_1.3.175.wso2v1.jar into C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\components\plugins\org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.4.40.jar into C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib
     [move] Moving 91 files to C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib\META-INF
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2\lib\org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
Username: admin
New password:           in

Re-enter new password:           in

log4j:WARN Error during default initialization
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/bootstrap/logging/LoggingBridge
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.<clinit>(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PasswordUpdater.run(PasswordUpdater.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PasswordUpdater.main(PasswordUpdater.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.logging.LoggingBridge
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 40 more
Error updating credentials for user wso2admin : org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while reading realm configuration from file
C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.5.0\wso2ei-6.5.0\bin>
```

- some Jar called `ant-contrib-1.0b3` placed after getting above error inside `apache-ant-1.10.7\lib` path

[image: ant lib path]

Is there any config i missed? or how to run that `chpasswd` command in windows 10 to reset password ?

Comment: After adding the `ant-contrib-1.0b3` did you get rid of the issue? Or are you getting the same error? The missing class it's complaining about is located in `wso2ei-6.5.0/bin/org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.5.3.jar` But the class missing error is a WARN it seems and the actual error you are getting is `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while reading realm configuration from file`

Comment: Hi @ycr
Thanks for your reply. Actually yesterday got 2 error. one is get rid of after placing ant-contrib-1.0b3 inside <EI-Home>/lib. another one is what i shown in error log. i noticed org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.4.40,jar is available in <EI-Home>/bin/. what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue for EI 6.5.0. If you have WSO2 subscription try updating the product. If not follow the instructions below.

**Note:** *I did not have a Windows environment to test hence I fixed this for a Linux environment. You can do a diff between the following file and include the required fixed in the `bat` file.*

Copy the org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.5.3.jar to the ${EI_HOME}/wso2/lib directory. This will get rid of the `NoClassDefFoundError` issue.

Then update the `chpasswd.sh` with the following content.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Copyright 2005,2006 WSO2, Inc. http://www.wso2.org
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Environment Variable Prequisites
#
#   CARBON_HOME   Home of CARBON installation. If not set I will  try
#                   to figure it out.
#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#
# NOTE: Borrowed generously from Apache Tomcat startup scripts.

# if JAVA_HOME is not set we're not happy
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  echo "You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running chpasswd."
  exit 1
fi

# OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
os400=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
esac

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '.*/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set CARBON_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CARBON_HOME" ] && CARBON_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." ; pwd`

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin; then
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CARBON_HOME" ] && CARBON_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$CARBON_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CLASSPATH" ] && CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --unix "$CLASSPATH"`
fi

# For OS400
if $os400; then
  # Set job priority to standard for interactive (interactive - 6) by using
  # the interactive priority - 6, the helper threads that respond to requests
  # will be running at the same priority as interactive jobs.
  COMMAND='chgjob job('$JOBNAME') runpty(6)'
  system $COMMAND

  # Enable multi threading
  QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y
  export QIBM_MULTI_THREADED
fi

ant -buildfile "$CARBON_HOME"/bin/build.xml

# update classpath
CARBON_CLASSPATH=""
for f in "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2/lib/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$f
done

for g in "$CARBON_HOME"/repository/lib/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$g
done

for h in "$CARBON_HOME"/wso2/lib/api/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$h
done

for i in "$CARBON_HOME"/bin/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$i
done

CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$CLASSPATH

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  CARBON_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CARBON_HOME"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"`
  JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

# ----- Execute The Requested Command -----------------------------------------
cd "$CARBON_HOME"

CARBON_CLASSPATH="$CARBON_HOME/lib/patches":"$CARBON_HOME/conf":$CARBON_CLASSPATH

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dcarbon.config.dir.path="$CARBON_HOME/conf" -cp "$CARBON_CLASSPATH" org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PasswordUpdater $*
```

Also note that you do not have to copy any additional drivers for H2 DB access as the product already have the driver installed. Also I observed a issue with your database URL. Refer the following command and fix your command accordingly.

```
sh chpasswd.sh --db-driver "org.h2.Driver" --db-url "jdbc:h2:../repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000" --db-username "wso2carbon" --db-password "wso2carbon" --username "admin" --new-password "newadmin"
```

References: https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/commit/0754a7130eacf88dccc960e92227f2c5635a63de

Comment: Hi @ycr,

Thanks for providing your workaround, windows chpasswd.bat file content is completely different than this linux chpasswd.sh file, will start to work on linux machine and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @ycr
I tried admin user account password reset in linux (ubuntu) distribution, after editing chpassword.sh as mentioned (https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/commit/0754a7130eacf88dccc960e92227f2c5635a63de) here, i can able to reset password for admin user. Thank you so much !!